# Get different items in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, colors, items

I read values from a .txt file and put them in a GridView using an ArrayAdapter and it works perfectly.
But I want to change the color of an item depending on the value of the item.

For example:
1 is Gray
2 is Red
3 is Blue
4 is ...

But I'm not able to change the backgroundColor of a single item in the GridView, only the whole GV.

```
GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvSpeelveld);
gv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

This attempt was unsuccesful

```
//View is null
View v = gv.getChildAt(2);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

But how can I get the different items of a single gridView? 
A for loop would be very useful.

[image: View app]

Comment: You have to set the background to individual item in the `getView()` method of Adapter...

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)` method of the adapter, get the value of the item at the given position (using the position param). Then use something like a switch-case and set the backgroundcolor for that grid item.

Something like this.

//say you get the item's value in the getView method...

```
switch(value){

case 1:
   view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); //grey
   break;
case 2:
   view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //red
   break;
}

//so on
```